# Sample code or app whic demostrate to do autorisation agains DNN7 WebAPI

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization, dotnetnuke

I start building my winforms app which uses DNN 7 as backend for authorization users.
My users are registered and approved on DNN portal, an idea is to my new WinForms Application use same users as DNN portal. I want to allow users to login in my app only if DNN webApi alow them to pass throught.
I cloud not find any sample code or demonstration who I can call DNN7 WebApi to authenticate user?
Closes I get is [Authorization in the new DNN Services Framework](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/3329/Authorization-in-the-new-DNN-Services-Framework.aspx) but sadly I am unable to understand that and to rewrite code on blog.
Is there any opensoruce module or any app which uses DNN WebAPI for Authorize users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fund what I am looking for It is [DnnDash Service](https://dnndashservice.codeplex.com/releases/view/97639) app.
They got also winForms App whic is opensource and demonstrate how to preform authentication.